# Reader Double Jumping Pages on Button press

Tags: sony-prs-t1, buttons

I have a Sony PRS-T1.
It's getting a little old, but its not too ancient.

Recently when I press the next page button, it has been jumping forward, 2 pages, as if i had clicked it twice.
Not every time, but quiet often (maybe every 3rd time).
Then I press back.
Very recently it has started doing this with the back button to.
Which means it is 2 steps forward, then 2 steps back then 1 step forward (assuming it doesn't skip again.)

To work around this I have been using the touch screen swipe to turn pages.
But I would like my buttons back.

I have not tried to do a factory reset as it sounds like a hardware problem.
Seems like maybe the buttons are bouncing.

Can I perhaps open it up and check nothing is caught under the buttons?
What could cause this effect?

Could it just be the buttons wearing out?
If so I guess I could replace the button, (if the soldering isn't too small)

Comment: I've got exactly the same problem with my t1. Your post is almost a year old, but I'd like to know if you managed to solve this somehow.

Comment: Not really, no.
It seems to be happening less. but not sure if that is just my perception